# NiftyNet Input/Output Data Type

Tags: niftynet

What data type does NiftyNet expect as input? I'm aware that NiftyNet reads and outputs data in the NIfTI file format, but I'm unclear about the typing of the individual data (e.g. 16 sint or 32 sint). Is it documented anywhere?

I only ask because I've been getting very grainy outputs (sometimes completely indiscernible) when performing brain segmentation with UNet, HighRes3DNet, and VNet. This happens even when I train the networks for relatively simple segmentation tasks, leading me to believe that my inputs are somehow getting misinterpreted at the byte level. Would anyone happen to know if this data mismatch is possible, and what datatype NiftyNet expects?

Answer (score 0):

The data-loading is taken care of by `nibabel`. The data processing is application-dependent, but for segmentation the input data is cast to `tf.float32` in `segmentation_application`.

Are you able to over-fit one training example such that the segmentation works? What type of pre-processing are you using?

Comment: I just tried overfitting on one simple training example that consists of: unlabeled: unprocessed skull scan / labeled: mask of the brain (values of 0 or 255). When I tried inferring on the same skull scan I got a completely black image (255). If data type isn't likely the issue, then what could be?

Comment: Can you change the values of the mask to `0` and `1` and see what happens?